# Getting rid of indexes in excel file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel, openpyxl

My python3.6-based server creates an excel-file using pandas 1.1.5 (code1) then it adds lines into it using openpyxl (code2)

code1:

```
import pandas as pd
    print("l_vars_init:", l_vars_init)
    data = pd.DataFrame(l_vars_init, columns = [ "Tilasto", "Taulukko", "Luontipäivä"])
    #storing into the excel file
    if not os.path.exists("media"):
        os.makedirs("media")
    data.to_excel(path)
```

output:

```
l_vars_init: 
[{'Tilasto': 'tilastot_plv', 'Taulukko': '111y', 'Luontipäivä': '2018-03-28'},
{'Tilasto': 'tilastot_slv', 'Taulukko': '111a', 'Luontipäivä': '2018-02-28'},
{'Tilasto': 'tilastot_slv', 'Taulukko': '111b', 'Luontipäivä': '2018-02-28'},
{'Tilasto': 'tilastot_slv', 'Taulukko': '111c', 'Luontipäivä': '2018-02-28'},
{'Tilasto': 'tilastot_slv', 'Taulukko': '111d', 'Luontipäivä': '2018-02-28'},
{'Tilasto': 'tilastot_ton', 'Taulukko': '111e', 'Luontipäivä': '2020-12-06'},
{'Tilasto': 'tilastot_ton', 'Taulukko': '111f', 'Luontipäivä': '2020-12-06'},
{'Tilasto': 'tilastot_ton', 'Taulukko': '111g', 'Luontipäivä': '2020-12-06'}]
```

code2:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.active
max_row = ws.max_row
ws.cell(max_row + 1, 2).value = stat
ws.cell(max_row + 1, 3).value = rdf_id
ws.cell(max_row + 1, 4).value = 2023-10-16
wb.save(path)
```

The first rows in the result excel-file have indexes, but the row added by openpyxl doesn't have:

[image]

This is annoying. Eiher I want to get rid on the column A in the whole excel or at least get rid of the numeric indexces in column A in the first rows or be able to add indexes for the latest line added by openpyxl 3.1.2, too.

Comment: `data.to_excel(path, index=False)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasted hours serching for the solutin without results, but this works!